# Essential windsurfing moves

Tags: training, windsurfing

In windsurfing there exist many different moves. Apart from the very basic techniques (like uphauling the sail), which moves are considered essential for windsurfing? Which order is good for learning them?

Comment: at some point, duck-tacking, because it is fun, and way easier that jibe when you begin.

Comment: I would put a basic navigation move first (typically tacking) so you can come back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you are past uphauling, it is not a move you are likely to use again. It is a high effort move that in high winds is next to impossible. The moves you will need to learn are:

- beach start
- tacking (where the nose of the board goes towards the wind - simple, but slow)
- correct foot and sail position
- gybing/jibing (where the nose of the board goes downwind - fast, but much more difficult)
- water start (where the wind lifts you onto the board)
- harness use

Beyond that you can start looking at jumps, or getting out into big surf.

A lot of the fun comes once you are comfortable with speed, understanding where the energy is in the plane, and knowing how to use the sail to your advantage - then you have a wide range of gybes you can use. Jumps also become fun at that point, as landing a big one requires fine balance between aerodynamic effects, kinetic energy, rotational energy and hydrodynamic effects on take-off.